# Android BLE: How to check if bonded BLE Device is available to connect

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently testing the Glucose Profile of BLE. In order to get Glucose Records the BLE Glucose Meter has to be bonded first. After the Device is bonded I don't get this device anymore in the `onLeScan` callback when doing `startLeScan`.

I however can get a List of all bonded BLE devices by using `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices();`

Now I want to filter the bonded devices for devices that are currently in range/available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if there are devices in range/available you need to scan, so that is not a solution for you given that you said they are not being detected for some reason.

Therefore, you could try to connect directly to the bonded device by knowing it Adress or Name.

```
    Set<BluetoothDevice> myBondedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    String MAC = "your device Adress"
    for(BluetoothDevice mydevice:myBondedDevices ){
        Log.i("BondedInfo", MAC + "   " + mydevice.getAddress());
        if(mydevice.getAddress().equals(MAC)){
            mydevice.connectGatt(mycontext,true,mygattcallback);
            break;
        }

    }
```

Or the most adequated aproximation(according to myself):

- Implement a broadcast receiver that detect bonding and connect when the device bonding is complete:

  ```
      BroadcastReceiver myServiceBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  final int state=intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE,BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

      switch(state){
          case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING:
              Log.i("Bondind Status:"," Bonding...");
              break;

          case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED:
              Log.i("Bondind Status:","Bonded!!");
              myBluetoothDevice.connectGatt(mycontext, true, myBluetoothGattCallBack);
              break;

          case BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE:
              Log.i("Bondind Status:","Fail");

              break;
      }     
  };
  ```
- Register it properly:

  ```
  registerReceiver(myServiceBroadcast,new IntenFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED));
  ```